# JQuery automate function for different <li> items

Tags: jquery, list, menu, automation

I created a little menu with an icon before every `<li>`, the icon is just an image which is positioned with css. So you get a button as `<li>` with the icon first and after the icon the word 'Home' eg.

When you hover a `<li>`, the icon becomes bigger and changes from a black to white image.
This is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ca-menu li:nth-child(1)").hover(
    function(){
        $(".icon").attr('src',"images/home2.png");
        $(".icon").stop().animate({width:32,height:32,marginLeft:-8,marginTop:-8}, 200 );

    },
    function(){
        $(".icon").attr('src',"images/home.png");
        $(".icon").stop().animate({width:16,height:16,marginLeft:0,marginTop:0}, 200 );

    });
});
```

As you can see this is only for the first child of  the `<ul>`. Now I don't want to copy paste this 4 times for al my 4 links in my menu. Is there a way that I can automate this?
Can you make a loop that goes from 1 to 4 that I can put in the `nth-child(i)`. **AND** is there a way it will automatically choose the pictures sources? (they are all in the map images but they have different names ofc: home.png,about.png, contact.png,...)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ca-menu li").hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find(".icon").attr('src',"images/home2.png").stop().animate({width:32,height:32,marginLeft:-8,marginTop:-8}, 200 );

    },
    function(){
        $(this).find(".icon").attr('src',"images/home.png").stop().animate({width:16,height:16,marginLeft:0,marginTop:0}, 200 );

    });
});
```